# Safari,not able to save list items

Tags: 2007, custom-form, browsers

I am using Safari 6.0.5 on mac 10.8.5 with SharePoint 2007.

I am trying to edit an existing entry in a list that has a custom edit form.

Edit is OK, but when I click OK or submit , nothing happens.  The edit form stays as is no change.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, Safari 6.x isn't a browser supported by SP 2007: [Web Browser support for SharePoint 2007 with SP2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2009/05/08/web-browser-support-for-sharepoint-2007-with-sp2.aspx)

Second, if it is a custom form we'd need more detail to be able to help you. Perhaps you would be best in contacting the company or person who created the form for you.